# More efficient way to assign multiple variables in a FOR loop?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

I'm trying to capture the output of ffprobe to assign to two variables - currently I just run the loop twice to captue the `encoder` and `codec_name` tag.  Is there a more effcient way to do this from within a single loop?

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags^=encoder -of default^=nw^=1:nk^=1 %%a 2^>^&1') do set "encoder=%%i"
echo !encoder!

for /F "delims=" %%j in ('ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream^=codec_name -of default^=nw^=1:nk^=1 %%a 2^>^&1') do set "codec_name=%%j"
echo !codec_name!
```

Here's the full code for info - it's a batch reverse function in FFMPEG.

```
@echo off
md "%cd%\_reversedFiles"

for %%a in (*.wav) do (
    SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
    for /F "delims=" %%i in ('ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags^=encoder -of default^=nw^=1:nk^=1 %%a 2^>^&1') do set "encoder=%%i"
    echo !encoder!

    for /F "delims=" %%j in ('ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream^=codec_name -of default^=nw^=1:nk^=1 %%a 2^>^&1') do set "codec_name=%%j"
    echo !codec_name!

    ffmpeg -i %%a -af areverse -c:a !codec_name! "\_reversedFiles\%%~na.wav" 
    bwfmetaedit "\_reversedFiles\%%a" -a --ISFT="!encoder!"
)
```

For ease of sharing it needs to be in a batch file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that both `ffmpeg` command lines return exactly one non-empty line each, you could execute them within the same set of a single `for /F` loop:

```cmd
    rem // Initialise variable that is going to receive the first line:
    set "ENCODER="
    rem // Capture the output of both `ffmpeg` command lines:
    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%F in ('
        rem/ // Execute both `ffmpeg` command lines one after another: ^
            ^& ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags^=encoder -of default^=nw^=1:nk^=1 "%%~a" 2^>^&1 ^
            ^& ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream^=codec_name -of default^=nw^=1:nk^=1 "%%~a" 2^>^&1 ^
    ') do (
        rem // This captures the first non-empty line of text:
        if not defined ENCODER set "ENCODER=%%F"
        rem // This captures the last non-empty line of text:
        set "CODEC_NAME=%%F"
    )
    echo Encoder: !ENCODER!
    echo Codec:   !CODEC_NAME!
```